# mysql crc32(datetime)

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by, crc

Доброго времени суток. Такой вопрос, datetime имеет размер 8 байт, при использовании crc32(datetime) у нас будет использоваться только половина данных т.е. 1000-01-0(все остальное отбросится)1 00:00:00. Получается, что запросы

```
    select * from group by col_datetime
    select * from group by crc32(col_datetime)
```

будут иметь различные результаты и crc32(col_datetime) будет неправильно отрабатывать, если нам важно учитывать дату с точностью до дня, время можно отбросить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> у нас будет использоваться только половина данных т.е.

Неверно. Аргумент функции и её значение - вещи разные. При вычислении CRC используется весь аргумент, а не его часть.

> Получается, что запросы [skipped] будут иметь различные результаты

Это верно. Разные аргументы могут иметь равные контрольные суммы.

> crc32(col_datetime) будет неправильно отрабатывать

Это неверно. Если у Вас ошибка в логике, это не ошибка функции, а ошибка автора кода.

> нам важно учитывать день, а время можно отбросить

Ну так и группируйте по дню

```
SELECT DATE(col_datetime) AS col_date, * 
FROM data_table 
GROUP BY DATE(col_datetime)
```

Comment: Уточнил формулировку того, что мне нужно. Нужно группировать записи по дате с точностью до дня.
А по crc32, достаточно ли его, точности для решения данной задачи?
Ибо datetime у нас 8 байт, то фактически мы будем группировать при использовании crc32, только половину значение(4 байта) или я не правильно понимаю логику работы?

Comment: @KordDEM *или я не правильно понимаю логику работы?* угу. *crc32, достаточно ли его, точности для решения данной задачи?* Нет, это решение при указанных условиях неприменимо. *Нужно группировать записи по дате с точностью до дня.* Решение дано.

Comment: Группировка GROUP BY DATE(col_datetime) отрабатывает 0.641 сек
Группировка по GROUP BY crc32(col_datetime) - 0,4
Различен ли будет результат?

Comment: @KordDEM Это нормально. Группировка по функции всегда фуллскан. *Различен ли будет результат?* Да. Проверьте - создайте две записи с одинаковой датой и разным временем, почти гарантированно при группировке по CRC они НЕ будут объединены в одну группу.